# "invalid package name" exception in bazel

Tags: cmd, syntax-error, bazel

I try to run this command:

```
bazel query 'buildfiles(deps(//tensorflow/core:core_cpu_impl))'
```

And get the error:

```
ERROR: invalid target format 'buildfiles(deps(//tensorflow/core:core_cpu_impl))': invalid package name 'buildfiles(deps(//tensorflow/core': package names may not contain '//' path separators
```

Environment:
Windows 10 x64
Bazel 0.25.2

Any idea?

Comment: Open a command prompt window, run `cmd /?` and read the output help pages for Windows command processor, especially the last paragraph on last help page. It explains that a file name (or any other argument string) containing a space or or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` must be enclosed in `"`. Character `'` has no special meaning for Windows command processor on parsing command line arguments, except for a __for /F__ command line. So use `bazel query "buildfiles(deps(//tensorflow/core:core_cpu_impl))"` and perhaps the result is better.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use double quotation instead of single quotation. 
I ran into exact same issue as you have. After looking into Bazel documentation, notice they are using double quotation.